# Joining two tables (through a link), one which may yield multiple rows, together into one result

Tags: php, mysql, join

Lets say I've got a table listing car brands or models:

**Cars**:

```
Id | Brand
-----------
1  | BMW
2  | Audi
3  | Volvo
```

And I've also got another table which links features.
**Link**:

```
Id | carid | featureid
-----------------------
1  | 1     | 1
2  | 1     | 2
3  | 2     | 2
4  | 3     | 1
5  | 3     | 2
6  | 3     | 3
```

And I've got the table listing the features.
**Features**:

```
Id | Feature
-----------
1  | A/C
2  | 4WD
3  | Heated seats
```

I want to list these results on my front page like this:

> **BMW**
>
> - A/C
> - 4WD
>
> **Audi**
>
> - 4WD
>
> **Volvo**
>
> - A/C
> - 4WD
> - Heated seats

What's the best/most efficient way of doing this (using PHP and MySQL)?

---

**Edit**:
I think I'm going to redesign my `Cars` database to look like this instead:

```
Id | Brand   | Feature
----------------------
1  | BMW     | 1,2
2  | Audi    | 1
3  | Volvo   | 1,2,3
4  | Citröen |
```

And then fetch `Features` beforehand and combine in PHP. I guess it's much easier, and I don't get a problem if I have a brand without a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Cars.Brand As Brand, Features.Feature as Feature FROM Cars, Link, Features WHERE Cars.id = Link.carid AND Features.id = Link.featureid Order By Brand
```

This should be the query, then use mysql_fetch_array and print the results

```
<?php
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $last='';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     if($row['brand']!=$last) {
             //if the previous brand is the same don't print it out
             //otherwise save the new brand and print it out
             $last=$row['brand'];
             echo "<b>".$row['brand']."</b><br>";
             }
     echo $row['Feature'] . "<br>";    
  }
?>
```

Comment: But this will only give me the first feature, and not all of them since we're grouping, right? So I have to `GROUP BY features` and then with PHP iterate through the results to get each of the results before moving on to the next brand or something? Any idea on how to make that simpler?

Comment: oh right, I'm sorry, use order by instead of group by and than pass throught the result using a cicle... I've updated the post, read now...